# Why should covariance of mean of Y and least-squares slope be 0?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, covariance, linear

I was studying simple linear regression analysis. I was studying the proof of variance of the least squares intercept estimator $\hat \beta_0$ which is in the image.

[image]

I understand the proof, but can somebody give an intuitive explanation of why $Cov(\bar Y, \hat \beta_1)$ should be $0$? Because this means that $\bar Y, \hat \beta_1$ are independent. And intuitively it doesn't make sense to me because doesn't the value of  $\hat{\beta_1}$ depend on observations $Y_i$ and thus $\bar Y$?

Comment: Imagine that all $Y_i$ change in the same way (e.g. +1). It wouldn't affect your estimate of the slope, only the intercept.

Comment: @nope Yes, but if $Y_i$ change in some other way (eg: half of them +1, half of them +5), the it would affect estimate of the slope.